# android studio button will not recognize context

Tags: android, button

I am trying to add some user functionality to my maps app, and I seem to not be able to create a listener for a single button as of right now.

also, I would like to create another class, and still be able to call all the google maps functions, would I just extend the mapsactivity?

here is the code for the button:

```
public void buttonOnClick(View view){
    Button checkPoint = (Button) view;
    checkPoint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        }
    });
}
```

The compiler does not recognize the this portion. It says it is not recognizable. I have been trying to follow all the examples and i cant find one that works haha

Comment: *"It says it is not recognizable"* - that's the actual error you get displayed in Android Studio?

Comment: Please click [edit] and add in additional context, as well as the _actual_ error that you are receiving. Voting to close due to lack of context. Also, why are you setting an `OnClickListener` in a button click method 0.o

Comment: where have you put this portion of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

in on-click listener program will give you error :

`The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined`

or with generate compile time error, So to define in program that current Dialog refer to **Activity** class not **View** class use:

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(<YourActivityClassName>.this)
```